# Setting autocapitalize to sentences doesn't work, but words does on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` set up in Interface Builder, linked into a class in which I set this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var conversationNameTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        conversationNameTextField.autocapitalizationType = .sentences
    }
}
```

Anything typed into the text field "looks like this" with no capitalization applied. Weird, I thought. So I changed it to capitalize words:

```
@IBOutlet weak var conversationNameTextField: UITextField! {
    didSet {
        conversationNameTextField.autocapitalizationType = .words
    }
}
```

And the field "Capitalized Everything As Expected With Words On". Why would it not be working for sentence case but working for words? I tried setting autocorrect on and off programmatically to no avail. And also tried resigning and becoming first responder before/after setting this. Feels like an apple bug.

Comment: Also tried setting the autocapitalizationtype right before beginning editing to make sure it actually was set late enough. Nothing. I'd understand if it never autocapitalized at all, but the mismatch between word and sentence feels really wrong.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or with the simulator?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm testing with both and it's a problem with both